# contentsOfDirectoryAtPath crashes

Tags: iphone

I want to list files in the directory in table view of navigation control.
It shows files in the directory.
But whenever I scroll down, my simulator crashes. What is the problem?
dirArray is defined in .h file as NSArray *dirArray.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]currentDirectoryPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    dirArray = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];      
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section {
    return [dirArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSString *fileName = [dirArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = fileName;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
dirArray = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
```

will have `dirArray` pointing to an autoreleased object. So by the time you are accessing it later, it is being deallocated. Either retain it.

```
dirArray = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil] retain];
```

Or much better, declare it as a property and do

```
self.dirArray = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should make property of the your array and @synthesize it.**

or

**you shold alloc array and relese it in the dealloc.**

Comment: I added dirArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; before calling contentsOfDirectoryAtPath and I released it in dealloc. It still crashes. Do I have to do property and synthesize even if it is used only inside?

Comment: 2011-07-04 16:06:33.032 NaviTest[1211:207] -[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1d090
2011-07-04 16:06:33.035 NaviTest[1211:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1d090'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)

Comment: It does't seem content of array problem. I used root, home directory. It all crashes. I used also NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents"]; But there is no file. Where is document directory in simulator?